# Image resolution for Google Chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

Is there any specific image resolution for images that are rendering on minicontroller and expanded view for both android and iOS.
Sometimes the images are not rendering on expanded view and this makes more curious about the image resolution.
Anyone faced image not rendering on mini controller or expanded view.?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your images are not too large for the target. You can define different images to be used in different places, such as mini-controller, notification, cast controller dialog, expanded controller and lock screen (use [ImagePicker](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/ImagePicker) class). For mini-controller, if you are using the default implementation, your image should be pretty small; I would say a 200x200 pixels should be enough. For the other places, again don't use something larger than you need; one reason for them not being loaded could be that they might be too big.